# Google Cloud VM is used 100% memory when we start django web app on server than stop working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, devops

Recently i deploy my django webapp on google cloud server. But when i start my webapp on server than server used 100% Memory and stop working after it. I have to restart server. I found error on server log but i didn't understood about it.

`Error watching metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1//?recursive=true&alt=json&wait_for_change=true&timeout_sec=60&last_etag=45891ddf4553df93": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

Can anybody help me on this?

I am new to google cloud and don't know much aboout google cloud VM.

I just know it that VM is stop working when my web app start.

Comment: What instance size are you using? Most likely it is too small. The reason for the error message is when you run out of memory, networking can fail.

Comment: I am using VM with 8gm ram and 25GB memory.

Comment: `used 100% Memory` means the instance size is too small. Never run out of memory.